# Azure Pipelines - conditionally use a stage based on a variable group

Tags: azure-pipelines

Using Azure Pipelines, I'd like to select a template depending on a variable group.

In my library I set a variable group `MyGroup`, where a variable `useA` can have the value `true` or `false`

`azure-pipelines.yml`:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
- group: MyGroup

stages:

- ${{ if eq(variables.useA, true) }}:
  - template: './stages/A.yml'

- ${{ if eq(variables.useA, false) }}:
  - template: './stages/B.yml'
```

**Questions**

Could we conditionally run a different stage depending on a variable set in the pipeline?

I also tried `- ${{ if eq($['variables.useA'], 'false') }}:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could we conditionally run a different stage depending on a variable
> set in the pipeline?

Yes, you can.

**But,** if you want to use variable groups in condition expression, it is impossible.

**Reason:**

[image]

This information you can refer to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax

> To reference a variable group, use macro syntax or a runtime
> expression.

This information you can refer to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-variable-group

**So the situation you encountered is caused by the variable group in yml doesn't have such usage.**

But you can use Variable directly with no problem:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
- name: useA
  value: true

steps:
- ${{ if eq(variables.useA, true) }}:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        Write-Host "Hello World"
```

Successful on my side:

[image]